# How to 'hide' the actual email address when sending an email with PHP?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Just a quick question. Basically I have a PHP script which sends an email to someone within my organisation. It all works well but there is a small 'problem'. Usually someone receives an email from another in the organisation it simply has their name, e.g 'Joe Bloggs' in the from field. But when I send it from the PHP script it also has the full email address in it, e.g. `Joe Bloggs <jbloggs@domain.com>`. Is it possible to only have the name as opposed to the name and email address showing in the email?

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using the standard php function `mail()` you can specify the outgoing email adress in the additional email headers like this:

```
mail("mail.to@example.com","subject" ,"body message","From: SPECIFY.THIS.ADDRESS@example.com\nContent-type: text/html");
```

Comment: Tried that but keep getting an error in my script <br/>
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address in C:\wamp\www\Flook\email.php on line 11
<br/>
If I omit the full email address. Basically I want to be able to effectively use the email names as opposed to the addresses, I dont exactly want to hide the email address when the email is received in outlook (happy for the email to be right clicked on to find out who it is from), I just don't want the email address displayed in the email heading when it is received in outlook.

Comment: i think this problem is than mail-server related: it's not about php functionality, but about the settings of your mail servers. if the mail server administrator forbid creating new outgoing email aliases than you must set up the mail server, not php. try to ask under different tag line `mail-server` or the name of your mail server package. they will tell you, which setting to choose to have the possibility of endless email aliases